# How to use --var in SASS?

Tags: css, sass

how can i use CSS variables in SASS file? I tried:

```
:root
  --app: red
```

OR

```
$color

:root
  --app: #{$color}
```

I want the result to render as:

```
:root {
  --app: red
}
```

but it doesn't work, I get **SassError: invalid CSS, expected 1 selector or at-rule, was "root: {"**

How do I select this **:root** in SASS file?

**FIXED**
I uninstalled **node-sass** and installed **sass** and it works. Ty for helping :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can check this link for more information
https://sass-lang.com/documentation/breaking-changes/css-vars

SASS

```
$accent-color: #fbbc04

:root
// WRONG, will not work in recent Sass versions.
--accent-color-wrong: $accent-color

// RIGHT, will work in all Sass versions.
--accent-color-right: #{$accent-color}
```

SCSS

```
$accent-color: #fbbc04;

:root {
  // WRONG, will not work in recent Sass versions.
  --accent-color-wrong: $accent-color;

  // RIGHT, will work in all Sass versions.
  --accent-color-right: #{$accent-color};
}
```

Comment: Yes, I saw it, I tried it (my example number 2) and it still doesn't work